# Indexing array with array on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

It is similar to some questions around SO, but I don't quite understand the trick to get what I want.

I have two arrays,
**arr** of shape (x, y, z)
**indexes** of shape (x, y) which hold indexes of interest for z.

For each value of **indexes** I want to get the actual value in **arr** where:

```
arr.x == indexes.x  
arr.y == indexes.y  
arr.z == indexes[x,y]
```

This would give an array of shape(x,y) similar to indexes' shape.

For example:

```
arr = np.arange(99)
arr = arr.reshape(3,3,11)
indexes = np.asarray([
[0,2,2],
[1,2,3],
[3,2,10]])
# indexes.shape == (3,3)

# Example for the first element to be computed
first_element = arr[0,0,indexes[0,0]]
```

With the above `indexes`, the expected arrays would look like:

```
expected_result = np.asarray([
[0,13,24],
[34,46,58],
[69,79,98]])
```

I tried `elements = np.take(arr, indexes, axis=z)`
but it gives an array of shape (x, y, x, y)
I also tried things like `elements = arr[indexes, indexes,:]` but I don't get what I wish.
I saw a few answers involving transposing indexes and transforming it into tuples but I don't understand how it would help.

Note: I'm a bit new to numpy so I don't fully understand indexing yet.
How would you solve this numpy style ?

Comment: "but I don't get what I wish": It is not clear what you wish exactly. Can you give an example with some dummy data? E.g. if `arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`, then what would `indexes` look like? And what is the expected result then?

Comment: What would be the resulting array in this case, you have only given the first element of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html)

```
import numpy as np

#sample data
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.arange(3*4*2).reshape(3, 4, 2) # 3d array
idx = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3, 4))   # array of indices

out = np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(arr, idx[..., np.newaxis], axis=-1))
```

In this code, the array of indices gets added one more axis, so it can be broadcasted to the shape of the array `arr` from which we are making the selection. Then, since the return value of `np.take_along_axis` has the same shape as the array of indices, we need to remove this extra dimension using `np.squeeze`.

Another option is to use [`np.choose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html), but in this case the axis along which you are making selections must be moved to be the first axis of the array:

```
out = np.choose(idx, np.moveaxis(arr, -1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, it does wonders ! I'm accepting this answer because it should work for n dimensional array not only 3d (even though it was not in my question) and there is no need to reshape.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here should work for you: [Indexing 3d numpy array with 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532688/indexing-3d-numpy-array-with-2d-array)

Adapted to your code:

```
ax_0 = np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]
ax_1 = np.arange(arr.shape[1])[None,:]

new_array = arr[ax_0, ax_1, indexes]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform such an operation with [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html), the operation can only be applied along one dimension so you will need to reshape your input and indices.

The operation you are looking to perform is:

```
out[i, j] = arr[i, j, indices[i, j]]
```

However, we are forced to reshape both `arr` and `indices`, *i.e.* map `(i, j)` to `k`, such that we can apply `np.take_along_axis`. The following operation will take place:

```
out[k] = arr[k, indices[k]] # indexing along axis=1
```

---

The actual usage here comes down to:

```
>>> put = np.take_along_axis(arr.reshape(9, 11), indices.reshape(9, 1), axis=1)
array([[ 0],
       [13],
       [24],
       [34],
       [46],
       [58],
       [69],
       [79],
       [91]])
```

Then reshape back to the shape of `indices`:

```
>>> put.reshape(indices.shape)
array([[ 0, 13, 24],
       [34, 46, 58],
       [69, 79, 91]])
```